# How to transfer RTF from richtextbox to MS Word, without using Clipboard?

Tags: c#, ms-word, richtextbox, rtf

I need to transfer RTF (RichTextBox) to MS Word.
But transferred RTF data was broken. like this.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg949\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1042{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset129 \'b1\'bc\'b8\'b2;}}
{\colortbl ;\red135\green206\blue235;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1042\f0\fs18 AAA\highlight1 AAAAAAAAAA\highlight0 AAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
\par
}
```

How can I solve this problem? 
It can be done with the Clipboard. But I want another way, as DataObject or other objects.

This is my code.

```
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */
//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
**oPara1.Range.Text = richTextBox1.Rtf;**
```

Comment: I tried, DataObject object. but failed.
    DataObject obj = new DataObject();
    obj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, richTextBox1.Rtf);

--> oPara1.Range.Text = (string)obj.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf);

It is same result before.

Comment: What's wrong with using Clipboard Object then putting that into your word document? what is the value of `ref oMissing` .?

Comment: If I (or other Applications) clicked "Cltr+C", might happen error. So I need to avoid it.

Comment: is this an automated process? how can another application get or gain access to your application(s) please explain ..you don't click Cltr+C you hold down those keys..

Comment: Yes, this is an automated process that creates multi word documents. It will takes time 1 or 2 minutes. I worry about long duration. Running a process, if I click Ctlr+C, a clipboard data in an automated process would be changed. So I want another way.

Comment: well is this process going to be running on your machine or on an Application / Remote Server..?

Comment: This is a C# application with form. It is going to be running on each local machine. not remote server..

Comment: if it runs on individual machines then I don't see how Clipboards can be shared.. ? this doesn't make sense based on your question..

Comment: Many users will use this program. Many users...I just want to avoid Unexpected errors. so, is not there any way for transfering RTF without Clipboard?

Comment: We did something like this on one of our projects at work but we consumed a web service to handle this..